# ASP.NET WebForms Complex GUI Ideas

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

Hi Im currently creating ASP.NET WebForms app which is a rewrite from Winforms and I have a complex entry form with a deep object graph. One to many in which each of the child(many) has also Many children. in winforms i did this with nested modals any GUI ideas on how should I approach this on ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into ASP.NET MVC, that's nicer way to organize your app into views.

Comment: Yup I can also do ASP.NET MVC but my problem is in 1 View(Page) i have a master-detail-detail relationship my winforms app was designed. I needed an Idea how to do it in web. it seems awkward to have multiple nested modals(jquery ui or bootstrap) right? I just wanna know what others did when they encounter a complex relationship in 1 View(page/Form)

Comment: You can do multiple views and route to them.  Alternatively you can use SinglePageApplication approach and use AngularJs for example.

Comment: Already did that angular js with ui-bootstrap to show the modals also created mini SPA instead of the whole application. doing it was a lot of plumbing work so thats why i opted for webforms since the application is just for corporate intranet less than 30 users i was hoping to use webforms(Component framework) because it was for me a bit more practical than to hand craft from MVC(Action framework) the result from the users view is still the same plus script manager and update panel saves me lot of time. But the wall im hitting is GUI layout ideas for this kind: master-detail-detail view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using MVC Partial views, ex:
If you have a controller named CustomersController, and inside it you will have the Index action which renders the list of customers.

Inside the view, you will display the list of customers and with each a customer a link that shows the orders, when you click the link, it can open a bootstrap dialog and its content will be retrieved from another action that returns PartialViewResult, the action will accept the customer ID, and inside the view, you will list the orders.

In the Orders view, you can have another link to another action that returns the Product details using another Partial view.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. my issue is somewhat the same. mine is. let say you have Order - OrderLineItems- and each line item can have multiple attribute so its master-detail-detail on 1 page Order(header) OrderLineItem(Detail/Table) Attributes of LineItem( modal popup form). Do you think i should split them per view? master - 1 view, detail - 1view, detail - 1view? but i think the user might not appreciate it. they want to see is a header and detail like the purchase order entry form in SAP

Comment: If you mean you want to draw it at once as if it is a report, then it will be simply, just build the view model with the hierarchy you want and in the view, just iterate over the model and draw the content.

Otherwise, use the approach i mentioned above and load it using Ajax, this way, the user experience will be good as well as the performance, so you will only retrieve the data upon clicking the master record

Comment: That would be good. but its not read only its an order entry form with headers and line items that you can CRUD

Comment: No problem, you can build the order line items using knockout or any other library and upon save, just post the data to an action using ajax, just make sure the posted JSON has the same property names and structure as your Model object in the controller and MVC model binding will fill the properties for you

Comment: I've already done that using angularjs but the approach requires more work. I could have achieved the same using webforms. but my real problem here is the layout of master-detail-detail regardless mvc or webforms. any sample pictures or ideas that i can follow?

Comment: Can you describe exactly the scenario you are trying to do from a user perspective and I will suggest to you a good way of this can be done regardless the technology used.?

Comment: Purchase Order Entry Form(1 Page) - Has a purchase order Header and Line items where you can add a line item set its quantity and cost and each line item can have multiple attributes for Shirt it can have(Color, Size..etc). Btw thanks for helping me and for the effort and all..

Comment: I got your point, in this case you need to unify the displayed attributes, i am sure all the items will have a title or a name, quantity, price and image, so you can display these fields in the line items grid, if the user wants to view the details specific to an item, ex: the shirt color and size, then you can do this in another modal dialog which will get the line item and check its type and accordingly load the related attributes.

displaying different attributes will not be user friendly

Comment: Yup thats it. Thanks.. you think I should choose WebForms to make my dev simple right? usually if i do the same thing in mvc it would take more time and work to accomplish.

Comment: On the long term, MVC will be better and the code will be more manageable and maintainable specially if the project size become big, Web Forms is fast to start but I will not use it for any new project, you can even check the new features in Web Forms and compare it to MVC, Asp.Net Core has no Web Forms .
Good luck, please always contact me if you need any help

Comment: Okay thanks for your help @Haitham Shaddad!